# passar valores do checkbox para a url

Tags: php

Boa tarde,
Pessoal estou com uma duvida em como fazer para passar os itens selecionados de uma pagina para uma URL emitir um relatorio todo o codigo ja esta funcionando bem bacana so falta essa parte.

exemplo

```
item     codigo
1        11
2        12
3        13
4        14
5        15
```

como faço ao selecionar o checkbox dos itens 1,2,5 seja repassado uma url da seguinte maneira www.teste.com/realatorio.php?id=1,2,5

```
<?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($saldo_financeiro2)) {
                    $cliente = $row->nome_cliente;/* dentro do $row[] vai o nome da coluna da sua consulta */
                    echo '<tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="input-field" type="checkbox" name="age" value="'.$row->item.'"/>
                        <label></label>
                    </td>';
                    echo "<td>".date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row->codigo))."</td>
                    </tr>";
                }
                ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque não repassa via POST? via GET é mais fácil de manipular resultados, confuso, acho eu

Comment: e como seria via post? pois com varios dados assim ainda nao consegui fazer

Comment: Consegue me ajudar @AndréBaill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer algo assim

```
<input type="checkbox" name="age" <?php if (isset($age) && $age=="1") echo "checked";?> value="1">1-9
<input type="checkbox" name="age" <?php if (isset($age) && $age=="10") echo "checked";?> value="10">10-19
<input type="checkbox" name="age" <?php if (isset($age) && $age=="20") echo "checked";?> value="20">20-29
<input type="checkbox" name="age" <?php if (isset($age) && $age=="30") echo "checked";?> value="30">30-39
```

Do lado do servidor recebe como um $_POST['age']

```
 $ages = $_POST['age'];
 print($ages[0]);
```

Comment: vou postar meu codigo de como ele monta essa extrutura ai

Comment: pois quando eu coloquei o seu se eu selecionar um nao consigo selecionar mais nem um outro e ao tentar acrescentar o `<?php if (isset($age) && $age=="10") echo "checked";?>` gera erro

Comment: Peço desculpa pus type=radio e é type=checkbox

Comment: estou tendo dificuldades de inserir esse input dentro de um echo `<?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($saldo_financeiro2)) {
                    echo '<tr>
                    <td>
                        <input class="input-field" type="checkbox" name="age" <?php if (isset($age) && $age=="30") echo "checked";?> value="'.$row->item.'" />
                        <label></label>
                    </td>';
                    echo "
                    <td>$row->codigo</td>
                    </tr>";
                }
                ?>`

Comment: Retire o <?php if (isset($age) && $age=="30") echo "checked";?> e tente novamente de resto parece me bem

Comment: nao consigo selecionar nada

Comment: deve ter o tag input type checkbox mal escrito veja se esta a fazer bem http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41232/discussion-between-cristiano-cardoso-silva-and-pho3nix).

Comment: tive que formatar o resultado da seguinte forma `$id_trabalho = implode( ',', $_POST['age'] );`

Answer (score 0):

window.history.pushState(data, null, 'url_alvo');

Você terá que fazer uma função, por exemplo, com jquery.

```
$('checkbox').on('click', function(){
   window.history.pushState(null,null,'index.php?id'+$(this).val());
});
```

OBS: É um recurso do HTML5, dependendo do broswer pode não funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Como faço ao selecionar o checkbox dos itens 1,2,5 seja repassado uma url da seguinte maneira www.teste.com/realatorio.php?id=1,2,5.

Essa foi a sua pergunta a minha resposta, criada justamente o seu exemplo de url que é www.teste.com/realatorio.php?id=1,2,5.

no HTML você cria os inputs eu criei essa classe pra orientar o que está acontecendo

```
<input type="checkbox" valor="1">
<input type="checkbox" valor="2">
<input type="checkbox" valor="3">
<input type="checkbox" valor="4">
<p class="url"></p>
```

No Jquery você faz a criação de sua URL

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // www.teste.com/realatorio.php?id=1,2,5
    var url = Array();
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            url.push($(this).attr('valor'));
        }else{
            url.pop($(this).attr('valor'));
        }
        var terminar = url.toString();
        $('#url').html('<p>www.teste.com/realatorio.php?id='+terminar+'</p>');
    })
})
```

No exemplo você vai criar uma url parecida com o que você quer
 "www.teste.com/realatorio.php?id=1,2,5" , marcando os inputs checados irá traser o valores .
Espero que tenha ajudado.

Esse é um exemplo de como você pode fazer sua url .